# Omit a group of acronyms from the List of Acronyms using `glossaries`

Tags: glossaries

I am using `glossaries` to handle my acronyms. 
However, there are some of those that I initially wanted as acronyms but which I subsequently started to use only in their expanded form, i.e. in the text I always call this acronyms using `\acl{}`.

Even though these acronyms are defined in my code, I would like them not to be included in the list of acronyms.
Is there an option of `glossaries` that allows to do so?

Obviously, I could replace all the instances of `\acl{}` from said acronyms in my text with their expanded form, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an "ignored" glossary. These types of glossary are skipped by `\printglossaries`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newignoredglossary{ignore}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym[type=ignore]{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\begin{document}
\acl{html} and \acl{xml}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of result]

Alternatively, you can move an entry to an ignored glossary after the entry has been defined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newignoredglossary{ignore}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\glsmoveentry{xml}{ignore}

\begin{document}
\acl{html} and \acl{xml}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces the same result.

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Nicola.

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine the `\acl` command to print just the definition without indexing the acronym

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\acl}[1]{\glsentrytext{#1}}

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{css}{CSS}{cascading style sheets}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}
\newacronym{sql}{SQL}{structured query language}
\newacronym{rdbms}{RDBMS}{relational database management system}
\newacronym{rdsms}{RDSMS}{relational data stream management system}

\begin{document}
    These entries are only used once: \acl{sql}, \cgls{rdbms},
    \cgls{xml}. These entries are used multiple times:
    \acl{html}, \acl{html}, \cgls{css}, \cgls{css}, \cgls{css},
    \cgls{rdsms}, \cgls{rdsms}.
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

> Sidenote: to make it easier for us to give you an answer, please
>   provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/90297) next time.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works in the MWE. Sadly, in the template I'm using there is some additional problem but that calls for another question, I suppose. ;)